# How can i convert a DBQuery<T> to an ObjectQuery<T>?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, objectquery

I've got a `DBQuery<T>` which converts to an `IQueryable<T>` (this bit works fine). But then I'm trying to convert the IQueryable to an ObjectQuery .. which fails :-

```
public void Foo(this IQueryable<T> source)
{
    // ... snip ...

    ObjectQuery<T> objectQuery = source as ObjectQuery<T>;
    if (objectQuery != null)
    {
        // ... do stuff ...
    }
}
```

This used to work before I changed over to Entity-Framework 4 CTP5 *Magic Unicorn blah blah blah*. Now, it's not working - ie. `objectQuery` is `null`.

Now, `DBQuery<T> inherits IQueryable<T>` .. so I thought this should work.

If i change the code to ..

```
var x = (ObjectQuery<T>) source;
```

then the following exception is thrown :-

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to
>   cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Tests.Models.Order]'
>   to type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Tests.Models.Order]'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to cast it to ObjectQuery?

Comment: I think you're going to need a method that takes a DBQuery and constructs an ObjectQuery. That or an explicit conversion. I realize either one of those is a pain, though.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  DbQuery doesn't have a direct relationship to ObjectQuery, unlike DbContext vs ObjectContext.  I doubt that a direct conversion is possible.  Again, you should re-examine why you need the cast in the first place.  Also, where is "source" coming from?

Comment: I need to get access to the `Include` method, which an `IQueryable<T>' does not BUT an `IObjectQuery` does.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`DbQuery<T>` contains `Include` method so you don't need to convert to `ObjectQuery`. `ObjectQuery` is not accessible from `DbQuery` instance - it is wrapped in internal type `InternalQuery` and conversion operator is not defined.

Btw. when you add `using System.Data.Entity` and refrence CTP5 you will be able to call `Include` on `IQueryable<T>`!

Comment: no way! wikid :) It sure does! In fact, int's in the CTP5 System.Data.Entiy.DbExtensions namespace! And the code is (more or less) exactly what I had for my EF 3.5 code. (I made my own Include extension methods of `ObjectSet` (er.. i think it was `ObjectSet` ..) Dude - THANKS SO MUCH! win win win ...

Answer (score 11):

Using reflection, you can do this:

```
var dbQuery = ...;
var internalQueryField = dbQuery.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("_internalQuery"));
var internalQuery = internalQueryField.GetValue(dbQuery);
var objectQueryField = internalQuery.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("_objectQuery"));

// Here's your ObjectQuery!
var objectQuery = objectQueryField.GetValue(internalQuery) as ObjectQuery<T>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do with it, but would a `dynamic` variable help?

[Using Type dynamic (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

Comment: I don't think so, because I need to have an ObjectQuery<T> so I can get access to the Include method, on it.