# IDbSet and Exposing Include method via Extension Method

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first

I am using the Code-First approach with EF and I wanted to use IDbSet instead of DbSet so I could do Unit Testing with mocks. My problem is I use the Include() method for eager loading where necessary but Include() is not exposed via IDbSet. I saw an example code using an extension method to expose Include() but it doesn't seem to work for me; the objectQuery object in this example is always null. Please let me know how to fix this.

```
public static class IQueryableExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string path)
        where T : class
    {
        ObjectQuery<T> objectQuery = source as ObjectQuery<T>;
        if (objectQuery != null)
        {
            return objectQuery.Include(path);
        }
        return source;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path)
        where T : class
    {
        ObjectQuery<T> objectQuery = source as ObjectQuery<T>;
        if (objectQuery != null)
        {
            return source.Include(path);
        }
        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need to write such extension if you are using CTP5. [CTP5 provides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766122/how-can-i-convert-a-dbqueryt-to-an-objectqueryt/4769245#4769245) `Include` extension for `IQueryable`. You have to reference EntityFramework.dll (CTP5) and add:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Your version probably doesn't work because your are converting source to `ObjectQuery` but it will most probably be of type `DbQuery`.

Comment: I didn't get what you were saying at first. But then I realized I needed to have the using statement on the file where I was writing my linq  statement (services class) to use Include(), not just on the file I created my DbContext (session.cs). Thank you!!!

Comment: alas, the quest for unit testable EF has reached it's goal. THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the property `using` statements that contain the above static class. Simple copy/paste of your code results in IDbSet exposing the include methods when referencing the proper namespace.