# How to I get a DbCommand from an Entity Framework IQueryable

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

When using LINQ to SQL, I can use the [DataContext.GetCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand.aspx) method to get a DbCommand instance for an IQueryable. Now I'm using Entity Framework (code-first, but that shouldn't matter) and I want to get a DbCommand from an IQueryable that I generated against my DbContext.

**Is this possible? If so how?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any method to retrieve `DbCommand` from linq-to-entities query but you can try to convert the query to `ObjectQuery<T>` and call its `CommandText` property.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, although [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766122/how-can-i-convert-a-dbqueryt-to-an-objectqueryt#4769245) seems to indicate that I can't get an ObjectQuery from a DbQuery. I'll update if I have any luck.