# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

Tags: c#, database, linq, visual-studio-2015

My C# VS2015 application throws this exception:

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
>
> Message=Unable to cast
> object of type
> 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[ADONET4LINQtoENTITIES.Customer]'
> to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'.
> Source=ADONET4LINQtoENTITIES

The error occurs in the line that defines the query variable:

```
var customers = from c in de.Customers
                where c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderAmount > 150)
                select c;
 
string query = ((ObjectQuery)customers).ToTraceString();
```

My assumption is that `ObjectQuery` is prompting the exception.

I tried `string query = ((DbQuery)customers).ToString()` instead, which works in VS2013, but this resulted in the same exception.

Why does VS2015 throw exceptions with these query approaches?

Comment: The error message says it all: `customers` is of type `DbQuery<ADONET4LINQtoENTITIES.Customer>`, not `DbQuery` nor `ObjectQuery`.

Comment: Are you using the same version of EF when it worked and when it didn't? [It seems they're not related anymore.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766122/how-can-i-convert-a-dbqueryt-to-an-objectqueryt)

Comment: @manji that implementation worked like charm.  I just had to add: `using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure`, and adjust `ToTraceString()` to `ToString()` in the `query` definition.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Customers` is not an `ObjectQuery` what you want is an `ObjectQuery<Customer>` so remove the projection as well (the `Select`).

Change to

```
var CustomersQuery= from c in de.Customers
                    where c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderAmount > 150);

string query =  CustomersQuery.ToTraceString();
```

I took out the naming lexical ambiguity by naming it `CustomersQuery`.

See [ObjectQuery.ToTraceString Method (System.Data.Objects)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) for more information.

Comment: That would not be a valid linq statement. the `select` part of the query is required when in that form.