# Entity Framework - context disposed error

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
using(ctx e = new ctx())
{
   var pkg = from clPkg in e.PkgCoilPkgs.Include("PkgBand")
                               .Where(c2 => c2.PkgId == PkgID)
                               select new PkgCoilcls
                               {
                                  PkgCoilPkg = clPkg,
                               };
  return pkg.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

`PkgBand` is a foreign key table and lazy Loading enabled is set to true

statement: `var pkgBand = PkgCoilPkg.PkgBand.Name;`

throws

> The ObjectContext instance has been
>   disposed and can no longer be used for
>   operations that require a connection"
>   error.

Even though I am using `Include("PkgBand")` to load, Why I am getting this error?

Comment: And what happens if you don't use that projection?

Comment: are you sure you have the context instance? check with a brackpoint if e is null or not.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it using Projection ; select new { PkgCoilPkg, PkgCoilPkg.PkgBand }; Here is more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474951/entity-framework-include-is-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I fixed it using Projection ; select new { PkgCoilPkg, PkgCoilPkg.PkgBand }; Here is more info: [Entity Framework Include() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474951/entity-framework-include-is-not-working)