# Linq/EF, Eager loading and GROUP BY issues

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm having issues with GROUP BY and eager loading. I try to explain what im doing. 
I'm querying a datacontext ctx for events

The event class has the following properties

```
string Description
DateTime Date
bool IsDeleted
Guid SubjectId 
string Title 
DateTime Created
Guid ForProjectId 

Person TriggeredBy
List<Guid> Targets
```

There are muttiple events with the same SubjectId and i would like to end up having events with unique SubjectIds and that are the newest in the group. I end up with the following query.

```
var events = from x in
             (from e in ctx.Events
              .Include("TriggeredBy")
              .Include("Targets")
              group e by e.SubjectId
              into g
              select new 
                     { 
                       GroupId = g.Key, 
                       EventsWithSameSubjectId = g, 
                     }
              )
              select x.EventsWithSameSubjectId
              .OrderByDescending(y => y.Created).FirstOrDefault();
```

The query compile fine and returns the right resulting set. But the included properties are always null.

When i strip the query to see if eagor loading is working properly....

```
var events =  (from e in ctx.Events.OfType<DataNotificationEvent>()
              .Include("TriggeredBy")
              .Include("Targets")
              select e).ToList();
```

This return the events with all the included properties.

Is this a known issue / bug with Linq / EF or is there any way i can get rid of this error.

Regards

Vincent Ottens

Comment: There is an issue with eager loading when you combine it with grouping (and subselects and projections). Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474951/entity-framework-include-is-not-working/4475504#4475504 The two linked articles in the answer might help you to find a workaround.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're projecting onto an anonymous type, so `Include()` isn't going to work like that. Because what you've done with the `group` and projecting into the anonymous type is to change the shape of the query. That tosses out the eager loading. Reading [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx) might help.

Answer (score 2):

Thnx for the quick answer. You pointed me in the right direction. Here is the solution i came up with:

```
using MyFunc = Func<ExtendedCoreContext, Guid, IQueryable<DataNotificationEvent>>;

private static readonly MyFunc GetMentionsNewCompiledQuery = 

    CompiledQuery.Compile<ExtendedCoreContext, Guid, IQueryable<DataNotificationEvent>>(

        (ctx, personId) => ((ObjectQuery<DataNotificationEvent>)(
            from x in (
                from e in ctx.Events.OfType<DataNotificationEvent>()
                group e by e.SubjectId
                into g
                select g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Created).FirstOrDefault()
            )
            orderby x.Created descending
            where x.Targets.Any(t => t.Id == personId)
            select x
        ))
          .Include(EntityProperties.Event.TriggeredBy)
          .Include(EntityProperties.DataNotificationEvent.Targets)

    );
```