# LINQ to Entities Include() does not work

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

The following LINQ to Entities query (using EF 4.1 Code-First), is supposed to create a list of viewmodels based on `Campaigns` and `Users`. I have eager-loaded `Category` property of each campaign so that each campaign should have its `Category` reference property filled with appropriate data.  But it seems like this eager-loading is lost somewhere, thus I cannot access categories like: `campViewModels[0].Campaign.Category`. It's always null.

```
var campViewModels = ctx.Campaigns
.Include(c => c.Category)
.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(searchText)).Join(
    ctx.Users,
    c => c.CampaignId,
    u => u.CampaignId,
    (c, u) => new {c, u})
    .GroupBy(cu => cu.c)
    .Select(g => new CampaignViewModel { Campaign =  g.Key, MemberCount=g.Count()})
    .OrderByDescending(vm => vm.MemberCount)
    .Skip(pageIndex)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

For workaround this problem, I have changed my viewmodel definition and to have `CategoryText` property and filled it in my query:

```
Select(g => new CampaignViewModel { Campaign =  g.Key, MemberCount=g.Count(), CategoryText = g.Key.Category.Title})
```

But 
I'm curious to find out what prevented the explicit loading of categories?

Comment: Combination of `Include` and a projection is a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474951/entity-framework-include-is-not-working/4475504#4475504 (especially the links in the answer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Include` is ignored when you project to a new type, use a `join`, or a `group by`