# Listing entities pointed by foreign keys in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, performance, entity-framework

I have two Entities, let's say Car and Photo.
Each photo has foreign key to Car, so each car has set of its photos.

I want to list some subset of cars and for each listed car I want to list all of each photos.

How can I do this in Entity Framework with 1 db query?
I know from the beginning that I would need photos.

My code for now look like:

```
var carList = CarEntities.Where(...).ToList();
foreach(var car in carList){
    var photoList = car.Photos.ToList();
}
```

I think, EF would do separately db query for each car.

Comment: "I think, EF would do separately db query for each car."  Why do you think this?  Or do you mean for each car's photos?

Comment: Let's say D -fk-> C -fk-> B -fk-> A. If I list all AEntities in EF I probably don't want list all BEs pointed any A, all CEs pointes any ... So I think EF would get from db data when needed, it would be when I call `A.Bs` ar `A.Bs.First().Cs` or sth like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell Entity Framework in include Photos when querying Cars.

```
var carList = CarEntities.Include(c => c.Photos).Where(...).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

ckal's answer is pretty close except use include in the end otherwise EF may not always include it (cant recall exact reason at the moment),

```
var carList = CarEntities.Where(...).Include(c => c.Photos).ToList();
```

Edit: Here's the reason... [Entity Framework Include() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474951/entity-framework-include-is-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and give you feedback tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

"Select new" is what you likely want to do. Create a new class called `CarWithPhotos` and use that to return a set of results:

```
var carWithPhotos = from car in CarEntities
                    where (...) 
                    select new CarWithPhotos(car, car.Photos.ToList());
```

As I understand it, this compiles to one a single database trip, which I think is what you're after.

**Edit:**  I've used this technique when the objects I'm querying are large and I don't always want to retrieve an entire "Car" object for example.

Comment: I don't want to create fake class for this. I want to use EF features to work with all I have. Otherwise it won't work for more complex usage.

Comment: The other answers will work just fine. I've edited my answer to give some rationale behind why someone else might use my approach.