# EntityFramework 4 upgraded to 5, lambda is not available

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have upgraded my "entityframework 4" project to 5. I want to use lambda expression in Include (my motivation is to suplant string definitions) brackets.

At this momemnt I have:

```
context.WarrantyContract.Include("Car");
```

And want to achieve this one:

```
context.WarrantyContract.Include(w => w.Car);
```

But when I try to replace string, visual studio is not eable to recognize my will.

I'll appreciate any right direction.

Comment: What is the type of your `WarrantyContract` property?

Comment: ObjectSet<WarrantyContract> and this in the brackets inherits from EnityObject

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [lambda version of the Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is declared in the `System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions` class as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

In order to use it you need to add an `using` with the right namespace in your file the:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

//...

context.WarrantyContract.Include(w => w.Car);
```

Comment: Enough to add namespace `using System.Data.Entity;`. @nemesv Thanks for the quick help