# EF Core NullReferenceException on Related Navigation Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-3.1

I have two related models.

```
    public class Offer
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string OfferCode { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        // more properties

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // more properties

        public virtual ICollection<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to have an MVC form with a select HTML element where Offers are grouped and products
and have the Product Names serve as optgroups.
To this end, I have a view model that I intend to populate with the grouped Offers and I have a method
to do just that.

```
        private OfferMessageViewModel PrepareViewModel(OfferMessageViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var offers = _context.Offers.Include(o => o.Product).ToList()
                .GroupBy(o => o.Product.Name).ToList();

            foreach (var offerGroup in offers)
            {
                var optionGroup = new SelectListGroup
                {
                    Name = offerGroup.Key
                };

                foreach (var offer in offerGroup)
                {
                    viewModel.Offers.Add(
                        new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = offer.OfferCode,
                            Text = offer.Description,
                            Group = optionGroup
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
            return viewModel;
        }
```

The code gets tripped up in the `GroupBy` clause.
`o.Product` is null even when `o.ProductID` has a value in it.

The `ToList()` call right before the `GroupBy` is not helping.

I have tried removing the `virtual` modifiers on the related entities 
navigation properties but the error persisted.

Installing the NuGet package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` and 
modifying and configuring it as such

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies() 
                .UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

also did not make the error go away.

Is there something else I am missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
It has been suggested that my post might be solved by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474951). But I get the null reference exception even with lazy loading explicitly turned on.
I have tried the suggested solutions there but still no luck.

Comment: @AliK Forgive me but I thought _context.Offers.Include(o => o.Product) is exactly what that is doing. Including the related Product. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Try doing _context.Offers.Include("Product") instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Include() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474951/entity-framework-include-is-not-working)

Comment: @MohammadAli Thanks for the suggestions but those fixes don't work for me.

Comment: @MohammadAli I found the fix. Posted it as the answer. Once again thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved it.

Apparently the problem was that the foreign key was an `int` referencing a primary key of type `long`.

So I changed

```
public int ProductId { get; set; }
```

to

```
public long ProductId { get; set; }
```

in the `Offer` model.
Added the necessary migration, updated the database and now it works.
No more null reference exceptions.

Don't know why I missed that but it's probably a combination of lack of sleep and 
a not-so-helpful error message throwing me off in a completely different direction.